# Remove "\n" if re-pattern is not found in the line

Tags: python

I am trying to build an analyzer for WhatsApp-Chats. The problem is, whenever in chats someone uses paragraphs, it creates a new line in the textfile of the chat as well (which did not before). I want my script to remove "\n" and add a space in the beginning of the line.

The textfile looks like this:

```
01.01.22, 00:00 - Anil: This is a sample.
01.01.22, 00:01 - Laura: This is a sample.
This is a new line, which belongs to Laura.
```

But it should be like this:

```
01.01.22, 00:00 - Anil: This is a sample.
01.01.22, 00:01 - Laura: This is a sample. This is a new line, which belongs to Laura.
```

I figured out the pattern:

```
^\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}. \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}
```

If pattern is not found in the line, it should remove "\n" and add a space in front of it. But I don't know how to do an if-statement regarding regex. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: How do you read in the data? Line by line or as a multiline string?

Comment: f.read().splitlines()

Comment: But if you use `splitlines`, there are no newline characters in the strings anymore?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to have any if/else statements. If you have your whole text, then you only need to use the `sub` command to replace specific newline characters which you can find with a negative lookahead:

```
import re
text="01.01.22, 00:00 - Anil: This is a sample.\n01.01.22, 00:01 - Laura: This is a sample.\nThis is a new line, which belongs to Laura."
print("Before:\n" + text)
print("After:\n" + re.sub("\n(?!\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}. \d{1,2}:\d{1,2})"," ", text))
```

Output:

```
Before:
01.01.22, 00:00 - Anil: This is a sample.
01.01.22, 00:01 - Laura: This is a sample.
This is a new line, which belongs to Laura.
After:
01.01.22, 00:00 - Anil: This is a sample.
01.01.22, 00:01 - Laura: This is a sample. This is a new line, which belongs to Laura.
```

explanation:
`"\n(?!\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}. \d{1,2}:\d{1,2})"` matches a newline `\n` that is not followed by `\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}. \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}` which we simply replace with a single space `" "`

You will need something like

```
text=f.read()
```

to read your text as a whole

Comment: Thank you, but it is really hard to understand what exactly this line is doing, so I can understand what is happening: print("After:\n" + re.sub("\n(?!\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}. \d{1,2}:\d{1,2})"," ", text))

Comment: which part do you need further explanation for? The [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) command syntax? The explanation of what the regex is matching is found in the answer and you can also investigate it a bit further using a site like regex101.com